# how to fix compiler error undefined reference

Tags: c++

I am not sure why I am getting this error. The function should return `true` or `false`.
All variables have been defined and the error I get is:

```
/tmp/ccTspEHr.o: In function `main':
rectangles.cpp:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `rectangle_name(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<Rectangle, std::allocator<Rectangle> >)'
rectangles.cpp:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `rectangle_name(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<Rectangle, std::allocator<Rectangle> >)'
rectangles.cpp:(.text+0x7b0): undefined reference to `rectangle_name(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<Rectangle, std::allocator<Rectangle> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Function prototype:

```
bool rectangle_name(string prompt, string invalid, string used, string n, vector<Rectangle> rectangle);
```

function definition:

```
bool rectangle_name(string prompt, string invalid, string used, string & n, vector<Rectangle> rectangle)
//This function reads in a prompt and reads in the name of the rectangle or stop\

{
  cout << prompt;
  getline (cin, n);
  // do other stuff and return true or false
}
```

What causes these errors?

Comment: Double check your signature vs. the definition. They don't match (`n` parameter).

Comment: When posting questions about errors, please post the error with the question, complete and unedited. Please edit your question to include the errors. Also please show the declaration of the variables involved.

Comment: Please edit your code to be a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry,  added the error, and I did not show the declarations because I thought the code was too long.

Comment: This was asked **literally half an hour ago.** I cannot possibly imagine the amount of research you put in this question.

Comment: Actually I've been working on this since last night and all of the errors I've seen involved reading in a file, which is not what I am trying to do. This is why I posted the question. Their answers were not relevant to mine. @H2CO3

Answer (score 3):

You declared

```
bool rectangle_name(string prompt, string invalid, string used, string n, vector<Rectangle> rectangle);
                                                                 ^^^^^^^
```

and defined

```
bool rectangle_name(string prompt, string invalid, string used, string & n, vector<Rectangle> rectangle)
                                                                 ^^^^^^^
```

See the fourth parameter? Declaration `string n`, and definition `string & n`. They don't match. Make those two match and the error will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. You should define the function. You declared the function as

```
bool rectangle_name(string prompt, string invalid, string used, string n, vector<Rectangle> rectangle);
```

but defined another function

```
bool rectangle_name(string prompt, string invalid, string used, string & n, vector<Rectangle> rectangle)
```

Notice the declaration of the parameter with name 'n'.